# Modify command to process all files in a folder

Tags: text-processing

I am currently using the following command to create image gifs from a video

```
ffmpeg -i '/home/video/test.mp4' -vf fps=1/180 '/home/video/test.mp4%03d.jpg' && ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i '/home/video/test.mp4%03d.jpg' -vf scale=160x110 -r 30 '/home/video/test.mp4.gif'
```

I would like to modify this command so that it can be used for every .mp4 file in a folder instead of just `test.mp4` as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use for loop of shell script
in your case

```
for i in *.mp4 ;
do
   ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf fps=1/180 "/home/video/$i%03d.jpg" && ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i "/home/video/$i%03d.jpg" -vf scale=160x110 -r 30 "/home/video/$i.gif";
done;
```

either run it directly or store it in a file say xyz.txt
and run `source xyz.txt`